# Metallb multiple ip(nic) in Layer 2 config

Tags: kubernetes, metallb

i have an on-premise kubernetes cluster setup with 1 master and 2 workernodes.
I have two adress-ranges where master and workernodes having ips in boths nets. Master (192.168.0.10 and 192.168.1.10), node1 (192.168.0.11 and 192.168.1.11), node2 (192.168.0.12 and 192.168.1.12). I can ping from each node to each other node with either ip adress. I can also ping both all adresses 192.168.0.x and 192.168.1.x from external network.

the adress range named "intnet" is 192.168.0.200-192.168.0.250
the adress range named "extnet" is 192.168.1.200-192.168.0.250
services requiering ips from extnet stall in pending state.

my metallb adress pool config is as follows

```
address-pools:
- name: intnet
  protocol: layer2
  addresses:
  - 192.168.0.200-192.168.0.250
address-pools:
- name: extnet
  protocol: layer2
  addresses:
  - 192.168.1.200-192.168.1.250
```

my service.yml is like the following

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sth1
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/address-pool: extnet
spec:
  selector:
    app: local-web
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
```

is not getting an external ip adress kubectl get svc shows "pending" forever. Whereas when i use "intnet" the service get quickly an ip address from intnet.

Can anyone help here? What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guided by the [official documentation](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/#advanced-address-pool-configuration) on this issue, you have to configure Metallb file removing the second line  `address-pools:`

```
address-pools:
- name: intnet
  protocol: layer2
  addresses:
  - 192.168.0.200-192.168.0.250
- name: extnet
  protocol: layer2
  addresses:
  - 192.168.1.200-192.168.1.250
```

Comment: Hi mycola,
thank you very much the solution, after correcting the metal-system config i am able to assign the right ip addresses.